# Symfony2 - choice constraint using Doctrine repository

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity, one of which properties I would like to validate based on a database query. I have it defined as a method in my repository, for example:

```
class EntryRepository extends EntityRepository {

    /**
     * Gets valid entries for validation
     */
    public function getValidEntries() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->where('s.isAvailable = :isAvailable')
            ->setParameter('isAvailable', true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I use this to provide available choices for the choice constraint? I could define it in my entity class like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SomeEntity {

    /**
     * @Assert\Choice(callback = {"Acme\MyBundle\Entity\EntryRepository", "getValidEntries"})
     * ...
     */
    private $entry;

    ...

    }
```

However, this would require me to make this method static in the repository, which isn't a good way to define repository methods.

Is there a way to do it properly? Or maybe I'm trying to reinvent the wheel and there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to create your own constraint and inject the repository as a dependency.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I contemplated creating a custom validation constraint, as Cerad suggested, but I've come up with something a little simpler - [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Entry;

class SomeEntity {

    /**
     * @var Entry
     */
    private $entry;

    ...

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
        if (!$this->entry->isAvailable()) {
            $context
            ->buildViolation('Entry is not available')
            ->addViolation();
        }
    }

}
```